# Why registering a module disables rewrite?

Tags: c#, asp.net

After I remove my `MyModule` module from the web.config file, the `rewrite` works as expected. **When adding the `MyModule` module back to the web.config file, the `MyModule` module works as expected *but the `rewrite` doesn't occur.***

web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="rule_name" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:7789/example/api/values" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <modules>
      <remove name="MyModule" />
      <add name="MyModule" type="My.Models.MyModule, Project1" />
    </modules>
    ...
```

RewriteModule.cs :

```
namespace My.Models
{
    public class MyModule: IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += Context_BeginRequest;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
        private void Context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // something is written here....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the top off my head, the first module to respond to a request will be the last. So if your module responds to the request, the rewritemodule won't be invoked.

Comment: And what your module is doing exactly? Or it is reproducable with empty module you provided in question?

Comment: @CodeCaster How can I make both the `rewritemodule` and `MyModule` work together?

Comment: @Evk `MyModule` will do an authorization before rewriting the request to someone else.

Comment: And if you remove all code from your module - will rewrite occur? And also, I think modules will run in order they are registered, so your module should run after rewrite, not before (but I'm not sure about that).

Comment: @Evk After removing the code from `MyModule.Init`, the `rewrite` still not occurs. How can I replace the order of `rewritemodule` and `MyModule`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the web.config - The `name` of the module must equal to the `type` (until the `,` in the `type`):

Change from:

```
<modules>
  <remove name="MyModule" />
  <add name="MyModule" type="My.Models.MyModule, Project1" />
</modules>
```

Change to:

```
<modules>
  <remove name="My.Models.MyModule" />
  <add name="MyModule" type="My.Models.MyModule, Project1" />
</modules>
```